# Php Booleans not working correctly?

Tags: php, logic, boolean

I have the following code, I seem to be having problems with booleans in php, when ever i dump out the value of bCreatedEvent it is just empty, what am i doing wrong and I'm using booleans wrong? It also fails my logic check so i can redirect at the bottom. I'm fairly new to php, but thought most of this should work similar to c/c++.

```
$dbTheatreCMS = new TheatreCMSDB();
                $iEventID = $dbTheatreCMS->InsertNewEvent($sTitle, $sCompany, $iCreateID, $sNotes, $sPrePrice, $sRegPrice);

                $bEventCreated = False;
                echo "bEventCreated1 = " . $bEventCreated . "<br/>";
                $bEventInfoInserted = True;
                $bEventRolesInserted = True;

                if ($iEventID > 0)
                {
                    $bEventCreated = true;
                    if (isset($_POST["Venues"], $_POST["EventDates"]))
                    {
                        $aiVenueIDs = $_POST["Venues"];
                        $adtEvents = $_POST["EventDates"];
                        if (count($adtEvents) == count($aiVenueIDs)) // These should be the same length
                        {
                            for ($i = 0; $i < count($adtEvents); $i++)
                            {
                                $bEventInfoInserted &= ($dbTheatreCMS->InsertNewEventInfo($iEventID, $aiVenueIDs[$i],$adtEvents[$i]) > 0) ? true :false;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (isset($_POST["Troupers"], $_POST["Roles"]))
                    {
                        $trouperIDs = $_POST["Troupers"];
                        $roles = $_POST["Roles"];
                        if (count($trouperIDs) == count($roles))
                        {
                            for ($i = 0; $i < count($trouperIDs); $i++)
                            {
                                $bEventInfoInserted &=  ($dbTheatreCMS->InsertNewTroupeInfo($iEventID, $trouperIDs[$i],$roles[$i]) > 0)? true:false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                echo "bEventCreated = " . $bEventCreated . "<br/>";
                echo "bEventInfoInserted = " . $bEventInfoInserted . "<br/>";
                echo "bEventRolesInserted = " . $bEventRolesInserted . "<br/>";

                $bEventCreated = $bEventCreated & $bEventInfoInserted & $bEventRolesInserted;
                echo "$bEventCreated = " . $bEventCreated . "<br/>";

                if($bEventCreated == True)
                {
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.localStorage.href = 'some page.php';</script>";
                }
```

**output**

```
bEventCreated1 = 
bEventCreated = 
bEventInfoInserted = 1
bEventRolesInserted = 1
0 = 0
```

Comment: 1. I'm not seeing a `bCreatedEvent` in your code? 2. If a variable is false, it will not print a `0` but a blank (`1` for true).

Comment: `echo` may not reflect the real variable contents (especially boolean variables that has the 'false'), use `var_dump()` to see content and the type of the variable.

Comment: whats the output of this :: var_dump($bEventCreated)

Comment: No, you have not just found a bug in the most basic and widely used data type of a hugely popular language, rest assured. ;o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

echo `false` will look empty use `var_dump($bEventCreated)`

Also `&` is a bitwise operator I think you mean `&&`

```
$bEventCreated = $bEventCreated & $bEventInfoInserted & $bEventRolesInserted;
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you always use identical or not identical comparison operators when doing a boolean condition:

`if($bEventCreated === TRUE)`

Comment: Yes. In fact, it's good to always use the type-safe === and !== comparison operators since they compare data-types and data-values.

Answer (score 0):

If a value is `false`, it will not `echo` or `print` a value. See for example:

```
<?php

$true = true;
$false = false;

echo $true."\n";
echo $false."\n";

var_dump($true)."\n";
var_dump($false);

?>
```

http://codepad.org/98bR4bfn

Answer (score 0):

There are some quirks with booleans in PHP. This two links may help:
http://pl.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php
http://pl.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting

Answer (score 0):

When you echo a variable it is first converted to a string.

When FALSE or NULL is converted to a string they are converted to an empty string, "". TRUE is converted to "1". Arrays are converted to "Array". Resources are undefined although they are currently converted like "Resource #N". Objects will throw an error if they don't implement __toString().